# How do i include a array?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, discord, discord.js

so i'm codding a xp system for a discord bot and i need some help. i want the bot to only give xp when a word is written. ex: i want to give xp when someone say touge in a string or whatever. but i also want it to add xp for other word. so i put all my words in a array an then im stuck.

here is my xp code:

```
if (message.content === "test"){
    let xpAdd = Math.floor(1);
    console.log(xpAdd);

    if (!xp[message.author.id]) {
      xp[message.author.id] = {
        xp: 0,
        level: 1
      };
    }

    let curxp = xp[message.author.id].xp;
    let curlvl = xp[message.author.id].level;
    let nxtlvl = xp[message.author.id].level * 300;
    xp[message.author.id].xp = curxp + xpAdd;
    if (nxtlvl <= curxp) {
      xp[message.author.id].level = curlvl + 1;
    }

    fs.writeFile("./database.json", JSON.stringify(xp), err => {
      if (err) console.log(err);
    });
  }
```

the first line is juste a test to see if the bot work and i need to replace it with my array thing.

thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

I would use the [Array#some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method.

```js
// the array of words to check for
const words = ['touge', 'bean', 'wine'];

// example message event
client.on('message', (message) => {
  if (words.some(word => message.content.includes(word))) {
    // do your XP stuff in here
  }
});
```

Comment: thank for the help it work. i have a other question. how can i make the xp reset after a lvl up ?